# localhost returns php but not htm

Tags: php, iis, localhost

I have installed IIS and php on Windows 7 Home Premium, using the download from 'http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx'.

I have placed files 'info.php' and 'index.htm' files in the localhost folder 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'. Both these are proven to work from a remote web site.

Opening 'http://localhost/info.php' works just as expected. This indicates to me that IIS is working correctly.

However, 'index.htm' does not open (neither does the 'isstart.htm' file placed there by the system). Firefox shows nothing at all - no error messages, and 'View Page Source' is empty. Internet explorer gives a 404.

If 'index.htm' is renamed to 'index.php' it opens as expected.

Why are 'htm' files being ignored by IIS?

Roger

Answer (score 0):

In your IIS, look for default document and click on it, try to add the extension htm, cuz usally is configured asp, aspx, html, after modification open the CMD and execute iisreset and test it.